# Need detailed view of a table column, when it is clicked(PHP+Mysql+HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table with information fetched from MySQL, but when i click on name column,it should fetch all details of that name and display in detailed view page.my edit and delete buttons work ,but i have no idea how to get a detailed view of the name and its related columns in a new page.kindly help me with that.Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table  class="table table-list-search  table-bordered table-striped  table-condensed ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <?php $apage = array('id'=>'','name'=>'');?>
              <script>var page_0 = <?php echo json_encode($apage)?></script>
              <h3>
                <a data="page_0" class="model_form btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add new record</a>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <?php $apage = array('id'=>'','name'=>'');?>
              <script>var page_0 = <?php echo json_encode($apage)?></script>
              <h3>
                <a data="page_0" class="model_form btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> View record</a>
              </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1;
                while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
                <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">
                  <td><?=$i;?></td>
                  <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form " href="#"> <?=$users->name;?></a></td>
                  <td><?=$users->bandwidth;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->connectivity;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->popname;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->popip;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->port;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->vlan;?></td>
                  <td><?=$users->nms;?></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a>
                  </td>
                  <script>var page_<?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php echo json_encode($users);?></script>
                  <td>
                    <a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info btn-sm "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>  
                  </td>
                </tr>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
            <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['flash_msg'])) :  
        $message = $_SESSION['flash_msg'];
        echo $error= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">
                      </span> <strong>'.$message.'</strong> </div>';
        unset($_SESSION['flash_msg']);
        endif;
      ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>  
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on('click','.model_form',function(){
           $('#form_modal').modal({
             keyboard: false,
             show:true,
             backdrop:'static'
           });
           var data = eval($(this).attr('data'));
            $('#id').val(data.id);
            $('#name').val(data.name);
            $('#bandwidth').val(data.bandwidth);
            $('#connectivity').val(data.connectivity);
            $('#popname').val(data.popname);
            $('#popip').val(data.popip);
            $('#port').val(data.port);
            $('#vlan').val(data.vlan);
            $('#nms').val(data.nms);
            $('#latitude').val(data.latitude);
            $('#longitude').val(data.longitude);
           if(data.id!=""){
              $('#pop_title').html('Edit');       
           }else{
              $('#pop_title').html('Add');
           } 
       });  
       $(document).on('click','.delete_check',function(){
         if(confirm("Are you sure to delete data")){
           var current_element = $(this);
           url = "add_edit1.php";
           $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: url,
           data: {ct_id:$(current_element).attr('data')},
           success: function(data) { //location.reload(); 
             $('.'+$(current_element).attr('data')+'_del').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
           } 
         });
         }
        });     
   });
</script>
<!-- Form modal -->
<div id="form_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i><span id="pop_title">ADD</span> POP INFORMATION</h4>
       </div>
         <!-- Form inside modal -->
         <form method="post" action="add_edit1.php" id="cat_form">
            <div class="modal-body with-padding">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>name :</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  class="form-control required">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>bandwidth :</label>
                        <input type="text" name="bandwidth" id="bandwidth" class="form-control required number">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>connectivity :</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="connectivity" id="connectivity" class="form-control required" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>popname:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="popname" id="popname" class="form-control required" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>popip:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="popip" id="popip" class="form-control required" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>port:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="port" id="port" class="form-control required number">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>vlan:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="vlan" id="vlan" class="form-control required number">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>nms:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nms" id="nms" class="form-control required number">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>Latitude:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control required" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>Longitude:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control required" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
               <span id="add">
               <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
               <button type="submit" name="form_data" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
               </span>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- /form modal -->



<script type="text/javascript">
  var $table = $('table');
  $table.bootstrapTable({ 
      search: true,
      pagination: true,
      buttonsClass: 'primary',
      minimumCountColumns: 2,
      columns: [{
          field: 'id',
          title: 'ID',
          sortable: true,
      },{
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Name',
          sortable: true,
      },
      
      {
        field: 'bandwidth',
          title: 'BANDWIDTH',
          sortable: true,  
      },
      {
        field: 'connectivity',
          title: 'CONNECTIVITY',
          sortable: true,  
      },
      {
        field: 'popname',
          title: 'SWITCH NAME',
          sortable: true,  
      },
      {
        field: 'popip',
          title: 'SWITCH IP',
          sortable: true,  
      },
      {
        field: 'port',
          title: 'PORT NAME',
          sortable: true,  
      },
      {
        field: 'vlan',
          title: 'VLAN',
          sortable: true,  
      },  
      {
          field: 'nms',
          title: 'NMS',
          sortable: true,
      },
      {
         
          title: 'OPERATIONS'   ,
      },
      {
          field: 'operation'    ,
          title: 'Action'   ,
      },
      ],
  });
</script>
```

**add_edit1.php*

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['form_data'])) :    
        $user_name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $user_bandwidth = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['bandwidth']);
        $user_connectivity = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['connectivity']);
        $user_popname = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['popname']);
        $user_popip = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['popip']);
        $user_port = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['port']);
        $user_vlan = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['vlan']);
        $user_nms = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['nms']);
        $user_latitude = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['latitude']);
        $user_longitude = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['longitude']);
        $id = ($_POST['id']!="") ? $_POST['id'] : '';
            if($id!="") :
                $query = " UPDATE `illt` SET `name`= '$user_name', `bandwidth`='$user_bandwidth',`connectivity`='$user_connectivity', `popname`='$user_popname' , `popip`='$user_popip',`port`='$user_port' , `vlan`='$user_vlan' , `nms`='$user_nms', `latitude`='$user_latitude', `longitude`='$user_longitude' WHERE id=$id";
                $msg = "Successfully Updated Your Record";      

                else:

                $query = " INSERT INTO `illt` SET `name`= '$user_name', `bandwidth`='$user_bandwidth',
                     `connectivity`='$user_connectivity', `popname`='$user_popname' , `popip`='$user_popip',
                     `port`='$user_port' , `vlan`='$user_vlan' ,  `nms`='$user_nms', `latitude`='$user_latitude', `longitude`='$user_longitude' ";    
                $msg = "Successfully Inserted Your Record"; 

            endif;
            $sql = $db->query($query);
            $_SESSION['flash_msg'] = $msg;
            header("Location:illmasterlist.php");
        endif;
        if(isset($_POST['ct_id'])) :
            $id = ($_POST['ct_id']!="") ? $_POST['ct_id'] : '';
            if($id!="") :
                $query = "DELETE FROM illt WHERE id =$id";
                $sql = $db->query($query);
                echo 1;
            else :
                echo 0;
            endif;
        else :
            echo 0;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: in your table you have `popname` is that what you'll like to get a detailed view of? i.e using the name you want to get other information from your DB related to that name?

Comment: no. not pop name.After id i have name (2 column) ,(<td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form " href="#"> <?=$users->name;?></a></td>
                            ) 
I am refering to it.if i click on that column ,it should fetch that full row details in a single page/modal form as i used for edit,add options

Comment: Get rid of the **illegible** `if() :` notation  ... use the regular way of braces `if(){}` and **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: i am not using mysql_* deprecated one .

Answer (score 0):

you want a detailed view of user when the username found here `<td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form " href="#"> <?=$users->name;?></a></td>` is clicked. You have it inside a link which is the first step. next step is to put the username inside the href and redirect to another page. Using `$_GET`you can retrieve the `username`  from the url and search for users in your DB with the `username`. what i mean is...

```
//add the href to your code which will redirect to 
//new page with url detailed_view.php?john doe
<td><a href="detailed_view.php?name='.$users->name.'"data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id?>" 
class="model_form " href="#"> <?=$users->name;?></a></td>
```

create a file called **detailed_view.php** (can be any name but change it to match the href redirect)

on that file use

```
<?php

session_start();
include("config.php");


if(isset($_GET['name'])){

$username = $_GET['name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM your_user_table_name WHERE name = '.$username.'";//your case table name is illt

$sql = $db->query($query);
while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {

echo $users->name','$users->id','$users->vlan','$users->popip;//and so on

        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: only a blank page opens with detaile_view.php after edit coding according to it, did i add html codings in detailed_view??

Comment: you should add all your html and edit the answer to suit your needs after the select query you have to display the result like you did before, check my edited ans

Comment: you can style the page as a table like you did before if you want it as a table

Comment: can u code detailed_view.php little deep,because i am confused

Comment: by above edition i am getting error like Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\admintemp\newmine\mine\illview.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\admintemp\newmine\mine\illview.php on line 14